# Generating maze in tile based game

Tags: java, tile

I am creating an RPG-type game and I am currently on world generation.  I am looking for a good way to generate mazes to use in the generation of forests.  I have looked at several algorithms, but none seem to work with tiles.  They all work with walls.  I cant use walls because by removing one wall I would have to remove the whole block because the game is made up only of square 16*16 pixel blocks.  The one that looks most promising currently is dfs but that still requires walls.

**Edit**: To clarify the problem with most algorithms is that they consider each spot of path to be a cell and the walls between the cells to take up no space.  In my game the walls take up exactly the same size as the other parts of the maze.  Because of this i cant find an algorithm suitable for generating the type of maze i want to generate.

Comment: Why can't you treat a tile as a wall? Are you going to have no impassible tiles? Kind of would defeat the purpose of a maze, wouldn't it?

Comment: no there will only be two types of tiles in maze path and trees no walls as path will only be one tile wide

Comment: So what defines the walls of the maze? Trees? Aren't Trees essentially walls then?

Comment: but you cant do something like this -+ in only two tiles

Answer (score 7):

You can create walls perfectly well with tiles by using four cells for every one space. For instance, the 3x3 wall-based maze:

```
+   + - + - +
|   |       |
+   +   +   +
|       |   |
+ - + - +   +
            |
+ - + - + - +
```

could be converted to the 7x7 tile map:

```
# . # # # # #
# . # . . . #
# . # . # . #
# . . . # . #
# # # # # . #
. . . . . . #
# # # # # # #
```

The conversion should be pretty obvious: for each 2x2 region, one corner is always a wall, the opposite corner is always clear, and the other two represent edges. (There's also half a region on one set of edges for the outer walls.)

Comment: That would depend entirely on how you're generating the maze, and how you represent it internally.

Comment: @Popgalop You can start by making a set of walls of the tiles by removing the center tiles that are never collisions, and then apply the maze algorithm normally to the wall tiles